# Error sending json in puppeteer and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, puppeteer

When I try to pass a parameter through the URL in express to send a json with puppeteer, another browser opens after a while and does not send the json, returns something empty.

```
   const express = require('express');
const path = require('path'); // NEW
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

const config = require('../src/config.js');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3006;
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '../dist'); // NEW
const HTML_FILE = path.join(DIST_DIR, 'index.html'); // NEW
const mockResponse = {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'foo'
};
app.use(express.static(DIST_DIR)); // NEW
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.send(mockResponse);
});
app.get('/getapi', async (req, res) => {

  function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

  const next_class = 'snByac';
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      dumpio: true
    });
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      await page.goto('https://adwords.google.com/ko/KeywordPlanner/Home?', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
      await page.waitFor(randomIntFromInterval(20000,25000));
      await page.type('input[name=identifier]', config.mail);
      await page.click('span.' + next_class);
      await page.waitFor(randomIntFromInterval(20000,23000));
      await page.type('input[name=password]', config.password)
      await page.click('span.' + next_class)
      await page.waitFor(randomIntFromInterval(39000,49000));
      await page.click('[icon="arrow_forward"]')
      await page.waitFor(randomIntFromInterval(3800,6000));
      await page.type('[aria-autocomplete="list"]', req.query.palabra)
      await page.waitFor(randomIntFromInterval(1400,2400));
      await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
      await page.waitFor(randomIntFromInterval(10000,14000));
      await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
      await page.waitFor(randomIntFromInterval(10000,14000));

      res.send(mockResponse);
      await browser.close();
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(HTML_FILE); // EDIT
});
app.listen(port, function () {
 console.log('App listening on port: ' + port);
});
```

I enclose the complete code, I don't get any console errors.
localhost has not sent any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
This, i get

Update: I solved it by placing within the route, the following: req.setTimeout (500000);

Comment: If you remove scraping code from the `getapi` route, does it still fail to send data?

Comment: Yes, when I remove the code if you send the data. The error arises when you type the keyword.

Comment: The error is probably displayed in the console too? Could you copy that error to the question? Also - is `config` object available inside of the route?

Comment: I enclose the complete code, I don't get any console errors.

Comment: I think it has to do with some of the response time, the longer I lose the maximum time, I don't know how that works.

Comment: I solved it by placing within the route, the following: req.setTimeout (500000);